# use nginx as k8s tcp proxy has some problem

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

use nginx as k8s tcp proxy has some problem

use proxy 9092 to forward kafka:9092,when kafka pod restart,other app cant connect kafka with nginx 9092 port,i check nginx log and found nginx still try to connect old kafka pod ip when kafka has been restarted and has a new pod ip.

my nginx conf like behind:

```bash
  kafka.conf: |-
    server {
      listen 9092;
      proxy_pass kafka-headless:9092;
```

i done know its a k8s issue or a nginx issue

Comment: Kafka doesn't use http protocol for communication, so it can't be fronted by an HTTP reverse proxy. [Follow this](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/)

Comment: its tcp proxy ,and before kafka restart i can connect it

Comment: I've run into problems before where Nginx doesn't respect DNS TTL.  Does using a ClusterIP Service (not the headless service) work better?  That Service would keep a consistent IP address even as brokers join and leave the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr @DavizMaze posting his comment as an answer. Pod IPs are usually ephemeral, that is why whenever a restart happens it will consistently change its IP address. You can learn more about Pods with [Pods Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/)

That is why it is recommended that to use the ClusterIP service since IP address is static and will change. Partly from this [link](https://medium.com/@danielepolencic/learn-why-you-cant-ping-a-kubernetes-service-dec88b55e1a3) it will explain how will the ClusterIP service worked to reach the pods.